# wildcard in functions - Online excel / google sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use this function with no success:

```
=sumproduct(--(g:g="coles*")*e:e)
```

I've tried both google sheet and microsoft online excel, and no luck in using that *.

Don't they support wildcard in functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a wildcard like that within an array-type formula.  You can get the same thing with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(G:G,5)="coles")*E:E)
```

[image]

You can use a wildcard in many other functions:

[Guidance](http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm)